# Java calling an object without using parameters

Tags: java

I am new to programming.  I have made this constructor:

```
public Attraction(int baseprice, String name) {
    this.baseprice = baseprice;
    this.name = name;
}
```

I have initialized the constructor in a different class:

```
Attraction attraction = new Attraction(ridename, price)
```

I would like to use  this data in a third class without having to pass in parameters, so it would look like this:

```
Attraction attraction = new Attraction()
```

This would then allow me to use getters and setters to change the existing data in  the attraction object. However, this is not possible at the moment because I have to pass in the name and price even though I  want to use the existing data.

Can anyone show me what to do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're not setting your fields through constructor parameters then set them to some default value such as 0, "", empty list etc.

Comment: your default constructor has to set some default values for baseprice and name

Comment: "but it does not set the data", so what kind of data did you expect it to set, given that you declared a parameterless constructor precisely in order to not have to set any data?

Comment: Just do yourself a favor and start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

You seem to misunderstand how java works.

The `new` name of the keyword to make new objects wasn't chosen at random: Every time you write `new Attraction([doesn't matter what goes here])`, a well, **new** object is made (this object is then 'an instance' of Attraction). Each individual object has its own set of the fields. There is also no 'one instance to rule them all' - there is no way to just go: "Give me the instance I created last" or "Give me the one instance; I never want more than one to exist".

You need to pass the reference around:

```
Attraction a = new Attraction(ridename, price);
... do stuff
someOtherMethod(a); // pass 'a' around via a parameter, or...
return a; // pass 'a' around by returning it, or...
this.someFieldOfTypeAttaction = a; // pass 'a' around by assigning it to a field.
```

many ways to do it.

You can also program 'give me the attraction I created last' or even 'there will only ever be a single attraction', but this doesn't sound right here: Surely you are planning to have many different attractions, and in general having global mutable state leads to spaghetti code that is hard to debug and which is prone to failure.

Comment: very clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a class like below

```
public static class Attraction {

    private String ride;
    private int price;

    public Attraction(String ride, int price) {
        this.ride = ride;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getRide() {
        return ride;
    }

    public void setRide(String ride) {
        this.ride = ride;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

So to create the class `Attraction` you need to pass two arguments. if you want to create an object without data and later you want to update it, you can make use of default constructor and later you can update the values of the object. like below

```
public static class Attraction {

    private String ride;
    private int price;

    public Attraction(String ride, int price) {
        this.ride = ride;
        this.price = price;
    }

    // this is a default construtor
    public Attraction(){
        this("", 0); // pass a default values for the object.
    }

    public String getRide() {
        return ride;
    }

    public void setRide(String ride) {
        this.ride = ride;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

later you can create object of `Attraction` with or without passing argument parameters.

```
    Attraction attraction = new Attraction() //will create the object with emptyString and 0
    attraction.setRide("Your ride"); //sets ride 
    attraction.setPrice(1233); // sets price
    attraction.getRide(); //gives the value of ride
    attraction.getPrice(); // gives the price of the ride
```

Or You can create with argument data.

```
        Attraction attraction = new Attraction("myRide", 20) //will create the object with value passed.
        attraction.setRide("Your ride"); //sets ride 
        attraction.setPrice(1233); // sets price
        attraction.getRide(); //gives the value of ride
        attraction.getPrice(); // gives the price of the ride
```